# Capybara Element not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara

I was wondering if someone could help explain to me why i am getting this error when the element can be seen on the test page. I am writing a test to essentially allow entries to be archived. At this point this is acting more as a separate saving mechanism to clean up the show page or at least allow it to be. The test is as follows.

```
     it "can archive a diagnostic report" do 
       diagnostic_info = FG.create(:diagnostic_info)
       diagnostic_info.save!
       visit admin_diagnostics_path
       page.should have_content("test message")
       click_button "Save"
    end
```

**The view**

```
= form_for [:admin, @diagnostic], url: admin_diagnostic_path do |f|
  .field
    = link_to :raw_json, admin_diagnostic_path(@diagnostic, format: :json)
  .field
    = label_tag :device
    = label_tag do
      %pre= JSON.pretty_generate(@diagnostic.data["device"])
  .field
    = label_tag :localStorage
    = simple_format(@diagnostic.notes)
    -if @diagnostic.data["localStorage"]
      = label_tag do
        %pre= JSON.pretty_generate(@diagnostic.data["localStorage"])
= submit_tag 'Save', method: :put, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }
= link_to 'Delete', admin_diagnostic_path(@diagnostic), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'really?' }
= link_to 'Edit', edit_admin_diagnostic_path
```

My error is below-It was passing ok before i added the click button save part

```
  1) /admin/diagnostics can archive a diagnostic report
     Failure/Error: click_button "Save"
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find button "Save"
     # ./spec/features/admin/diagnostics_spec.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: put a `save_and_open_page` before the `click_button "Save"` and inspect element to make sure its there. also you're mixing a use of form_for and form_tag, which might be a problem.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this and i got   Launchy::CommandNotFoundError:

Comment: add `gem "launchy"` in your gemfile

Comment: it was my mistake i did not realise it does not work from a vm. That said it still gives me the original capybara error-unable to find button etc which confuses me because when i view the site locally through the vm the button is there but when it opens it through capybara the link is not there?

Comment: any conditions or javascript that might be hiding it?

Comment: not that i can find!

Comment: so it turns out it was a problem with my routes. Thanks so much for your help though its put me a step ahead from the next potential error! Much appreciated!